# yum + list all available security updates without installing them, on redhat 5?

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

To list all available security updates without installing them, I run this

and this syntax is working on redhat 6 and 7

```
 # yum list-security --security
```

please advice what is the syntax for redhat 5?

Comment: `yum install yum-security`

Comment: I want only to print the list of sec errata that still not installed ( I not want to install them now )

Comment: [RHEL / CentOS: yum Lists / Installs Only Security Updates](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-fedora-centos-linux-yum-installs-security-updates/)  @Bratchley is correct as this is a plug-in, but only supports version CentOS v5.1 / RHEL v5.1 / Fedora v7 or above.

Comment: my version is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga) , so how it can be?

Answer (score 1):

---

See the first comment above : # `yum install yum-security`

And https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021 I.e. yum-security and yum-plugin-security are the required yum-files / plugins required when running yum commands concerning security updates.

---